# Getting exact matches in Lucene using the standard analyzer?

Tags: lucene

Given 2 documents with the content as follows 
"I love Lucene" 
"Lucene is nice" 
I want to be able to query lucene only for those documents with Lucene in the beginning , i.e , everything that will match the regexp "^Lucene .*".

Is there a way to do it , provided that I can't change the index , and it was analyzed using the standard analyzer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, take a look at SpanFirstQuery.  Here is a good tutorial:

http://www.lucidimagination.com/blog/2009/07/18/the-spanquery/